# Video I frame not working properly on mobile browser

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html5-video

I am just working on recording the video at user's end device. I am having problem with video screen size at mobile device. I have a website which is suppose to run on both browser on desktop and on mobile devices. Here is the image of how it is working on desktop browser, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1y4ey4buJo2ZWTXZtdzMLn8WJVOB42POI/view?usp=sharing). Everything works fine but now when I run it on mobile devices the screen comes like this, [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1N1pfFpBBsTUPt74sHTT_R55uhmhwWiLl/view?usp=sharing). So seems to me only half of screen is coming. I tried to adjust the width and height of video frame but not worked. Here are the HTML and CSS code for the implementation of above.

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="video-box">
    <img class="image-block__image image-block__image_camera" id='image' src="./images/box.png" alt="Place your face inside the square">
           <div id="video-box-video" class="">
                 <video id="myVideo" muted autoplay loop class="camera"></video>
                 <canvas id="faceCanvas" class=""></canvas>
           </div>    
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
video {
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    filter: FlipH;
}

.video-box {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    min-height: 210px;
    width: auto;
    top: 0px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    left: 0;
    /*border: thin solid yellow;*/
}

#video-box-video {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 210px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}

#video-box-video #faceCanvas {
    /*position: absolute;*/
    top: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    form: scale(-1, 1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
    transform: scale(-1, 1);
    filter: FlipH;
}
#myVideo{
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 100%;*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
}
```

**In JavaScript**

I am using window.MediaRecorder for recording the video.